# Space at the bottom of footer - CSS

Tags: css

**Q: How can I remove the space at the bottom most of my site using CSS?**

Site Url: `http://210.48.94.218/~yourplac/`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put your code on the question and create a jsFiddle. BTW, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem - do you mean the white space between your footer and the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this under your footer-div... and that cause the problem:

```
<div id="copyright" class="col-left">
    <p></p><p></p><p></p>
</div>
```

fill it out or remove it ...

Comment: This help me figure out a solution to my problem. Thanks.

Solution: 
What I did is set display value into "none" for #copyright element.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `margin-bottom: 10px;` from your `.col-left` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `margin-bottom` property on your `#footer col-left` element to `0`:

```
#footer .col-left {
    margin-bottom: 0; /* Used to be 10px */
}
```

It looks like it's on line 699 of `style.css`.